# Error " 'str' object has no attribute 'get 'when I've requested get-parameters from ssm using Aws CLI

Tags: string, get, attributes, command-line-interface, aws-ssm

[get-parameters of ssm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnSZ7.jpg)

Command i tried:

`C:\users\user>aws ssm get-parameters --names /myapp/dev/db_url /myapp/dev/db_password`

Result:
`'str'has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: Click on "get-parameters of ssm" above to view the picture

Comment: Please bring the text of your picture into the question body so that others will find it easier to answer your question.